# Nonconstructive proof of the irrationality of a power

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm given some rational $x$ and irrational $y$, I want to show nonconstructively that that $\exists x \exists y(x^y)$ is irrational.

I'm given the example $4^{\sqrt 2}$. It's just a one-liner. $4$ is rational, $\sqrt 2$ is irrational, and so $4^\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

I intuitively understand this, but is there a slightly more detailed explanation I can give to show that $4^\sqrt 2$ is irrational?

Comment: There are no conditions on $x$ and $y$ being rational or irrational? Otherwise you can just take some $x$ you know to be irrational from other sources and take $y = 1$.

Comment: O wait, it is in the beginning of your post: $x$ should be rational and $y$ irrational. Ok good, it is just confusing: fist you say 'I'm given' as if someone else gave them to you and you cannot change them, and then later you say $\exists$ which is like the opposite: you can choose them however you like with no conditions

Comment: But I guess now you mean: I want to show that there exists rational $x$ and irrational $y$ such that $x^y$ is irrational.

Comment: Oh no, I say "given" as in I'm given a proposition, not that $x, y$ are strict variables. I can pick anything for them, just as long as $x$ is rational and $y$ is irrational, and I find at least one example where $x^y$ is irrational.

Comment: I am not sure what your goal is here.  The proof that $4^{\sqrt 2}$ is irrational is highly non-trival (your one-lines is not correct, as has been remarked).  This was a Hilbert Problem (well, more or less).   Are you after an example of a rational $x$ and an irrational $y$ such that $x^y$ is irrational?

Answer (score 3):

Your "one-liner" is wrong.  $4$ is rational, $\log_4(9)$ is irrational, but $4^{\log_4(9)} = 9$ is rational.

EDIT:

What is true (by the Gelfond-Schneider theorem) is that $4$ is an algebraic number other than $0$ or $1$, $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational algebraic number, and therefore $4^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational (in fact transcendental).

But I think you were looking for something like this.  Consider $x = 2$, $y = 1/\sqrt{2}$.  If $2^{1/\sqrt{2}}$ is a rational number $r$, then
$$ r^{1/\sqrt{2}} = (2^{1/\sqrt{2}})^{1/\sqrt{2}} = 2^{1/2}$$
which we know is irrational.  Therefore there is at least one example with $y = 1/\sqrt{2}$ irrational and $x$ rational, either $x = 2$ or (if $2^y$ happens to be rational) $x=2^y$.

Comment: The statement isn't that for every rational x and every irrational y that $x^y$ is irrational. The quantifier here is for some. not for all

Comment: I wasn't objecting to the statement, just to the attempted proof.

Comment: I think Roberts objections is to the use of 'so' in 'and so $4^{\sqrt{2}}$  is irrational'

Answer (score 1):

As has been remarked, it is not so easy to show that $4^{\sqrt 2}$ is irrational.

If the goal here is to find a rational $x$ and an irrational $y$ such that $x^y$ is irrational then take $$10^{\log_{10} \sqrt 2}=\sqrt 2$$

To see that $\log_{10} \sqrt 2=\frac 12 \times \log _{10}2$ is irrational note that it suffices to prove that $\log_{10}2 $ is irrational.  But were it otherwise then $$\log_{10}2=\frac ab\implies 2^b=10^a$$ and, since $a,b$ are intended to be natural numbers, this is impossible ($b$ can not be $0$ and $5$ does not divide $2^a$ for any $a$).